# How can I support parallel development on a code porting project?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

The company where I work in the UK has a lot of VB6 applications which they wish to move to .net Core.

They want me to lead this, which is fine.

The problem is, the first application which they wish to re-write in .net Core. Development is also continuing on the VB application.

There is currently over 12 months of development scheduled for the old VB6 Application.

To me this is working on a moving goal post, and very hard if not impossible to achieve.

Because of this, it makes me feel extremely uncomfortable take this on. Once our team have developed this, we are going to have to keep going back over the old VB to see what has changed. This will just exacerbate any bugs.

The VB application is not under source control, it is just dropped on a file server somewhere.

To me what should happen is, development should stop on the VB application before any development is started on a new version.

My head is screaming don't do this, just wondered if anyone else had any thoughts?

Comment: Is it acceptable to your customers to stop all product development for 12 months while you rewrite the application?

Comment: @philipkendall, from the view outside of IT, of course not.

Comment: In that case I am very confused why you are saying that should happen.

Comment: @joestrazze he appricates my concerns, we have a meeting to discuss further tomorrow. I just wanted other peoples opinions, and to make sure its not me just awkward about it

Comment: Suggest that the title here can be edited to make it more specific.

Comment: Is there any reason for the customers to need development on the VB6 version to continue? If not, there's a business case here for stopping development of the VB6 version to focus on the .NET version.

Comment: Who are your users? Are these internal-facing applications where you can mandate that IT go around and update everyone to the latest version, or external where you have no control?

Comment: Btw why .NET Core? .NET Core 3.1 (latest version) is reaching end of life in December 2022. Go for .NET 6 immediately

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this question would fit much better on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is the planned development focusing on feature _addition_ or feature _rewriting_? The former wouldn't pose much of a conflict, albeit that you'd have to port the new features at a later stage.

Comment: @Philipp: actually it would be better on project management

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There needs to be a clear plan, with documented milestones for the rewritten project, and this needs to be done in conjunction with the ongoing development of the legacy codebase. This shouldn't just be about understanding what the current application *does*, it should also be about what people *want* the application to do - so you don't just end up rewriting the same bad ideas.

The first step is to understand where the legacy application will be in 12 months (or however long you think it'll take to develop the new one). If they're going to be removing features, you don't want to waste time writing them. If they're going to be adding new features (not a great idea on a legacy application), you need to know this so you can plan for them in your design.

You need to defined a minimum viable product (MVP) for the new application - which is the minimal set of features required for it to be usable by someone. Once you get to that point, development should be frozen on the legacy (with only bugfixes implemented), and all new functionality should be added to the new one. You'll probably have to run the two applications in parallel for a while until you reach feature parity on the new one.

The old application **needs** to be put into source control, and all future development needs to be recorded (tickets), and those bugfixes or features need to also be added to the backlog for the new application - so that you can keep track of what's changed since you started work. You shouldn't have to review commits to know what's changed - all the details should be recorded in the tickets.

If you've got a whole load of the legacy applications to rewrite over time, you should also be thinking about how to do that efficiently. Do they make sense as separate applications, or can you merge some of them? Can you write shared libraries with common functionality that you can re-use across multiple projects? Can you invest time in setting up a proper CI/CD pipeline and development environment now, to make the next one easier?

Good luck.

Comment: Watch out here for users who just will.not.switch until forced to as well as users who just don't report bugs. If your users are strongly in those camps (which most are) then don't assume that silence = all the new stuff works great. Often silence = "we tried it and it looked too new so we went back to the old one"...or worse, "we couldn't be bothered to upgrade to the new one, no idea if it works or not".

Comment: It's hard to overstate how common it is that users don't report bugs. Before Google added crash logs to their developer console, I inherited an Android app with no crash instrumentation, and added some. The number of crashes was unbelievable. Users never said a thing. And this was a commercial app they were paying big bucks for. There's an evil feedback cycle where everything sucks, users have very low expectations, and therefore it's hard to make a business case for fixing anything or even hiring competent developers.

Comment: @TechInquisitor Crashes are so common in Android applications that they just don't feel interesting to the user. Much the same thing happened with the web at one point - it has a lot to do with how common it is in general, and how much effort it takes to recover. Business applications can be even worse, since people often feel (and often rightly, of course) they have no control over the application and its development, so they just learn to ignore or work around the issues. And reporting bugs is hard, and sadly, often taken poorly by the management (on both sides).

Comment: @Luaan That's my point. It's not that hard to write Android applications that don't crash. My published apps have had zero crashes ever. Businesses hire extremely low quality developers who don't understand event-driven frameworks. And because everybody's doing that. there isn't much incentive to do better.

Answer (score 40):

First of all, that VB application should be under source control.

Second, you'd need to find a way to create an application that is a mix of .net and VB6. It's not something that I know about, but if that isn't possible, then you can forget about it.

Third, if this is possible, then you would move the application from VB6 to .net bit by bit, and as soon as something is moved, the VB6 code gets removed, and all changes are done in the .net code. At the same time, all changes in the VB6 code have to be reviewed to be minimal changes.

Now you take all this and tell your manager that he can have a rewrite of the VB6 application *as it is right now*, or you can start in a year's time, or development is changed the way you ask for.

Comment: This is the correct approach. I've done it. You take a piece/layer/component (ideally a stable one) and implement it in .net, then change the vb6 app to call it. Test like hell (step 0 is getting a test suite together, probably using ApprovalTests.) Remove the old stuff. Keep going until the vb6 app is a mere shell that calls all the new bits. (This may require changes to be made to both the new bits and the vb6 bits if they occur while a new bit is being written; make the new bits small enough to minimize this but large enough to minimize communication overhead.) Finally, replace the shell.

Comment: OP could put the VB application under source control, even if the creators aren't interested in doing it. It would certainly create clarity over the changes.

Comment: +1 - a full rewrite will offer no business value until it's complete and ready for production - that's a lot of investment for a very late return, and you need to dedicate a whole second team to writing it, who will either never catch up or inevitably get out of sync with the "legacy" app, making a big-bang cutover doomed to failure from day one. If you replace a module at a time you can test it and deploy it to production every day / week/ sprint / whatever to get the benefit of each incremental investment of time and effort...

Comment: ... It's more work to manage the project, but it's much more likely to succeed (or maybe just less likely to fail), and if priorities change at any point you can stop migration and still get the business value of the parts of the app you've already migrated.

Comment: We have also successfully used this step-to-step approach to modernize our MS Access/VBA applications with .NET (Framework, not Core) code. Most of the UI is still in MS Access, but the critical business logic has been migrated to .NET, which means we can use all the nice features of a modern development system (Unit Tests, LINQ, .NET libraries, version control etc.) without alienating our customers (our customers don't like it when the UI changes).

Comment: This is the only way this is ever going to work. Doing a total rewrite is doomed to fail

Comment: VB6 is built around COM, and .NET is really COM 2.0. The interop between the two is generally pretty easy (and you can even use VB.NET helpers if you want to reduce the friction further). This is absolutely the way to go, just don't expect the legacy team to be very happy about it :D

Comment: @KateGregory: +1 for tests. Lots of it. Without tests (and version control, duh), the project is bound to fail.

Answer (score 9):

The idea of moving a piece at a time to "better" technology is commonly called the Strangler Fig pattern. Check out https://paulhammant.com/2013/07/14/legacy-application-strangulation-case-studies/ and https://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerFigApplication.html .

Comment: You can throw in a bit of "Anti-corruption layer" as well (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer) to act as a shim between the nice new shiny .NET code and the ugly architecture of the legacy app. It's another layer of extra work which will ultimately end up in the bin when the project is complete, but it avoids baking compatibility with old design decisions into the new system.

Answer (score 5):

You really, *really* need that VB application in source control. As Clumsy cat [mentioned in a comment on an answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184717/how-can-i-support-parallel-development-on-a-code-porting-project#comment605099_184718), you don't need the VB developers to use that repo (though it would be helpful), nor do they even need to know or care that you're doing it. Simply bulk-copying the files to your checkout once a day or whenever and doing a commit will at least give you reliable tracking of what's being changed.

Git (and probably other VCSs) will inform you if your new copy is the same as the old one, in which case you don't need to commit that version. You may need to do a little bit of manual work for new and deleted files; ideally your copy program will delete existing files that were deleted from the source (`rsync` can do this) and your VCS will detect the deletions (as Git does with `git add .`). Depending on what else is in those directories, you may also need to create a `.gitignore` or similar to avoid committing things like log files.

Based on my experience, I agree with the other answers that suggest building a single application where parts are in VB and parts are in .NET if you can convince the VB team to go with you in that direction. It can take quite a lot of creativity to figure out how to do this, but the effort is almost invariably well worthwhile when compared to the cost of reworking the new source as the old source is reworked, handling the inevitable errors and even potential data corruption that can occur when two different chunks of code doing the same thing are in use simultaneously, and so on. (Martin Fowler has some further discussion and links about cost and risk management at [StranglerFigApplication](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerFigApplication.html); thanks to [Concrete Gannet's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/184733/67064) for that link.)

Many years ago I ported a PHP web application to Ruby over some time using exactly this method and, while it was quite a bit of work, it did turn out well. The core code that enabled this was fresh Ruby code that could read and write the PHP cookie format and, IIRC, a bit of work making APIs that allowed old code to call new code and vice versa. (Some of these were web requests that executed code in the other language; in other cases I used existing or made new stored procedures in the DBMS.)

And, of course, try to reduce scope and simplify the application functionality as much as possible during the course of this process. There are huge time and effort savings to be made by using a "redesign as you go" approach over trying to do exact copies of all the old bits of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Gnasher that a module-by-module approach could work. I would do it like this:

1. Analyse the current application. Find a framework to combine .net and VB parts. Identify modules that can be brought over to .net cleanly. Evt. refactor some VB6 to make this easier.
2. Once you have a module planned out for transition, coordinate a development freeze on that module. While translation is going on, there can simply be no work on that module. Make everyone understand that and include it in their development planning.
3. Repeat 2.

The analysis and architcture could go alongside the VB6 development (so long as you are adequately informed of changes -> establish source control, join planning meetings). The actual translation of modules should not go parallel to further VB6 development. Higher granularity of modules could make this less of a blocker, but could require more refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

In addition the the other fine answers, you need to commit **way** more resources to the new application than the old one, otherwise you will never catch up. Something along the lines of a 80/20 split in favor of the new application. Tell the product owners that this will significantly impact your ability to release new features for the old version, as a huge part of your 20% split will be devoted to just keeping the old version up-to-date and fixing bugs.

Example: If earlier, you had 90% new features and 10% bug fixes in the old version, you will now have 80% invisible work in the new version, 10% for bug fixes and just 10% for new features for the old version. 90% -> 10%. Where earlier you released 9 new features, there will now only be one! Even if the numbers are slightly different, never underestimate the slowdown and do communicate this!

Then you have to talk to product owners - *what is the minimum viable product for the new application*? Can you release that, and to whom, before the complete port is finished? Otherwise you'll have a seasoned, bug-fixed old version "working just fine" and a bungled release of the new version.

*And finally, what will the customers get*? A revamped UI/UX? New features only available in the new version? Otherwise your customers won't have an incentive to switch and will demand that you support the old version forever!

Comment: Indeed, putting the customer in the centre is critical. Work as closely with them as possible, especially if you want to go with the "start from scratch" approach - start satisfying customers ASAP. You don't have to satisfy _all_ the customers from the get go - pick the ones where you can get results quickly, and the ones who want new features the most. The sooner customers _want_ to use your new product, the bigger the chance you're actually going to _have_ a product.

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you from experience, that we have something similar going on for - porting a big (not huge) program from VB6 to C#. Since then the program is in a hybrid code state, and it's not exactly delightful to work on the VB6 part of it.

Given the effort and time it takes to be converted piece by piece, it took multiple years and is still going on. I wonder if it will EVER be finished. The product is in continuous use by customers, and new features are expected every year, so the manpower dedicated to this process is relatively low. Be reminded that the entire code base is a hot mess by now, so it is *really* difficult for new developers to get into it.

There is an easy, but somewhat drastic way to solve this: Create a new application from scratch, recreate all the parts of the old application in C#. Yes, the application will start with nothing, but at least it might be done in 6-12 months, and might have the bulk of the features after just 1-3 months (remember the Pareto Principle, the 20/80 rule).

In your case, I would do this: Stop working on the VB6 parts. Take ~1 month of time to create the structural parts in a new C# project, so that other developers can do their work there. A lot can be done independently of the main application - even UI elements, and then integrated: Encryption, file/folder management, e-mail client, web browser, web API related, text editor, or other features.

The hybridization of VB6 and C# (the alternative solution) is a nightmare that will haunt you forever. It will never be finished, at least it's quite possible you may never witness it. It is one of those permanent temporary solutions.

Comment: Was there a compelling reason to go VB6 => C# and not VB6 => VB.net?

Comment: I don't know. But based on how I can judge it, it was about modernization. There are more developers available for C#, it gets continuous upgrades, and it's just generally better in many aspects. The VB6 UI is clunky, hard to control (you have to set frame and window sizes manually), the editor is vastly outdated and the syntax isn't as nice. Sooner or later it was necessary to step away from it, as it was and still is a product that is continually developed.

Comment: -1 for a blanket statement on what the OP should do, with little understanding on WHY they may be asked to work in parallel.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Then tell me what that "WHY" is, what I misunderstood, and how it matters to this answer. He is free to reject my advise and do the eternal attempt to catch up - what he himself calls the "moving goal post." He is right about that and based on my experience he should avoid that.

Comment: For instance, there may be regulatory or contractual reasons why they have to update their software. There may be no window where there is no development. (I have no idea why you said it would take a month). There may also be an opportunity cost by choosing to suspend development. There may be potential lost customers who need minor changes to sign up, and that may go elsewhere if they can't be accommodated. In addition to all this, there are many many companies that continue to support a legacy product, that makes them significant sums of money.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie "May"? And why should I address every potential hypothetical? Should I also address the scenario in which electricity or internet is gone from the planet forever? If it's not mentioned in the question, we have to assume it is done so intentionally. But besides that: -- We know the company has the intention to transition to C# and continuing development, thus it's not a legacy product. Regulations and contracts were not mentioned. The point with the window of no development was addressed in the answer. The 1 month part is an estimation. "Signing up" is entirely unrelated.

Comment: Let me tell you from experience that a complete rewrite tends to backfire a lot more, and a lot more often. In one of the places I worked, there were 6 complete rewrites of the core product underway throughout the decade, and for bonus points, some of those were being developed simultaneously. The fact that noöne wants to work on the "legacy" part isn't particularly interesting, since you'll need to have people doing that anyway. You generally can't get away with not developing the legacy application. And of course, you always need good reasons to do any of this, not just management decisions.

Comment: @Battle You don't have to address every hypothetical, you can get away with making sane assumptions. You've made an assumption that development can be stopped on the legacy app for a period of time, but the OP has already pointed out that this is not practical from a business context.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - "can be stopped on the legacy app for a period of time" -> "[a] somewhat **drastic** way to solve this" -- Does "drastic" sound like something that can occur with no repercussions? This is my proposed solution and will require some sacrifices, risks and changes in the short-term. They may not want to hear it, they may not like it, but it's in my opinion the best way forward. And I think it is absolutely feasible if OP manages to be convincing and do it right. I wouldn't be surprised if he even thought about this exact solution as he wrote the question.

Comment: @Luaan - What went wrong? 6 complete rewrites of the core product sounds way too much. We have 1 core product that is in a VB6/C# hybrid state for almost a decade. We are talking about ancient programming languages with ancient tools vs modern ones, not about just "rewriting" the product from one relatively modern language to another. "isn't particularly interesting" -  It is though. People tend to leave, people tend to want to work on something else, and maybe you have to pay more for people versed in old languages or expect them to be old and possibly out of creativity or elan.

Comment: @Luaan - I for example could have been one of the developers on the main product, but I've shown that I am not interested. Instead I got way better tasks (currently on a major project) and got a good raise out of it even. I'd have long quit if I'd be forced to work on the main product, and the current project I am working on might not have come into existence without me.

Comment: @Battle Basically, people tend to severely underestimate how hard it is to "rewrite" something. Not on a technical level, it's not like anything we do is complicated - beyond managing complexity. But people (and _especially_ management, business and sales) have _no idea_ what makes the product work with users - or, to be more accurate, they have all the _wrong_ ideas. While people like to throw around the Pareto principle, they also forget that often those seldom used features are something that decide whether your software gets used or not.

Comment: @Battle At the same company, I've done a wonderfully successful "rewrite" of a legacy product through the iterative ("hybrid") approach. We could always focus where the results were the best, and prioritise and plan properly, while getting feedback from the customers very quickly (mind, this was a desktop application, so no "release every two weeks" for us). People never lost their tiny little features that were important to them, and we did a complete overhaul of everything. We never stopped pushing new features, because the code improvements made it much faster to add new things reliably.

Comment: @Battle Every time you decide to scrap everything, you're flushing out a lot of work that will _not_ be easier the second time around. And you will tend to make the same mistakes again and again, while losing customer trust and goodwill, and ultimately ending up with a product that will take another decade to "get good". And the whole time, you still _have_ to support the old, legacy product - except now you can't even sell the developers on the wonderful ride towards something better; they know they're the "maintenance" guys, with usually very low prospects and motivation.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to downvote this (after much thought) because while it's a valid approach, I think that it's irresponsible to suggest a from-scratch rewrite without an analysis of the downsides, or even just pointing out that, despite being a popular approach, it's quite prone to failure. (If you don't have any good stories about "let's rewrite it" failures, you have _very_ limited IT experience, even if you've spent a long time in IT. Full rewrite followed by fail is a classic IT story.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the others.  Definitely need to get the app in source control, no matter what.

Secondly, you need to assess whether the migration can be handled through an existing tool:

- Upgrade Wizard included in Visual Studio 2002-2008
- VB Migration Partner https://www.vbmigration.com/
- Any other tools you can find

*There's no reason to do things the hard way!  Use a conversion tool.*

Get the tools, **do a code freeze** and try them out.  Test.  If you achieve 100%, put the new code into source control.  If you can't, see if the gaps are something you can live with until you can remedy them.  If ultimately you still have to do parallel development, the tool is still going to help things quite a bit.

Comment: I am glad this answer mentioned “test”. But emphasize: write automated tests if they don’t already exist. For each module as they are converted. Read Michael C Feathers’ book, Working effectively with legacy code, where Legacy = any code that does not have fully automated tests

Comment: As well as VB Migration, check out Visual Basic Upgrade Companion by ArtInSoft (https://www.mobilize.net/products/app-migrations/vbuc). They were the authors of the VB Upgrade Wizard that was included with Visual Studio in the 2000s.

Answer (score 1):

Put the VB6 under version control.  It will have a 'main' / 'master' branch obviously.

Then create a 'ported' branch and base your C# on that.

Every few months or as often as you find necessary, merge *main* into *ported* and use the version diff. to see what you have to update in the C#.

---

Or ... develop an automated source-code translator.  There are various technologies based on Happy and other systems.  Then you work on the translator rather than the VB, and can track the moving target.